The new Google Places Swift SDK for iOS only results in Internal Error
I am building a new app and am trying to use the new Google Places Swift SDK for iOS. I am following these guides provided by Google:
Google Setup Guide and Google Text Search Guide
Unfortunately, I always get the following error:

Error fetching places: Internal Error
Error details: internal("Internal Error")
Error code: 2
Error domain: GooglePlacesSwift.PlacesError
User info: [:]

The main parts of my code look like this and are setup inside a Apple App Project:
// my content view
import SwiftUI
import GooglePlacesSwift

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    init() {
        PlacesClient.provideAPIKey("my API key")
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

// my google file
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import GooglePlacesSwift

func searchForPizzaInNewYork() async {
    // Define the bounds for New York City
    guard let region = RectangularCoordinateRegion(
        northEast: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 20, longitude: 30),
        southWest: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40, longitude: 50)
    ) else {
        print("Failed to create region.")
        return
    }

    // Create a SearchByTextRequest with the desired parameters
    let searchByTextRequest = SearchByTextRequest(
        textQuery: "pizza",
        placeProperties: [.placeID],
        locationBias: region,
        includedType: .restaurant,
        maxResultCount: 2,
        isStrictTypeFiltering: true
    )

    // Perform the search
    switch await PlacesClient.shared.searchByText(with: searchByTextRequest) {
    case .success(let places):
        // Handle the places retrieved
        for place in places {
            if let placeID = place.placeID {
                print("Place ID: \(placeID)")
            }
        }
    case .failure(let placesError):
        // Handle the error with detailed feedback
        print("Error fetching places: \(placesError.localizedDescription)")
        
        // Print additional details if available
        print("Error details: \(placesError)")
        
        if let nsError = placesError as NSError? {
            print("Error code: \(nsError.code)")
            print("Error domain: \(nsError.domain)")
            print("User info: \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

// my view
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            
            Button(action: {
                Task {
                    await searchForPizzaInNewYork()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Search for Pizza in New York")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

